# How to deal with HTTP/1.1 412 Precondition Failed Error?

Tags: http, delphi, indy, delphi-10.3-rio

I use the indy http component (tidhttp) to get the HTML content of any web site. It works for most web sites.

"**HTTP/1.1 412 Precondition Failed**" error is encountered if I try a certain web site (http://banque-en-ligne-global.com). The URL works on browsers.

```
var
  Http: TIdHTTP;
  MS: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Http := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Http.Get('http://banque-en-ligne-global.com', MS); // Error Here
  ....
end;
```

Is there any way to bypass the error and get the HTML content of the web site?

Comment: try to set the user agent to mimic a chrome or firefox browser, most sites have protection against scrapers.

Comment: Thank you for your idea. But unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: Response code 412 is *supposed* to apply only to a **conditional request** (a request with one or more `If-...` headers) to indicate the requested condition(s) have not been satisfied. But the code shown is not performing a conditional request. I have been able to reproduce the error using the latest Indy snapshot, and it is indeed a `User-Agent` issue. I can get rid of the error by changing `Http.Request.UserAgent` to `'Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)'` (amongst others I tried without error) instead of Indy's default of `'Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)'`.

Comment: So, I would consider this to be a server-side bug, the server is misusing an HTTP response code for a purpose it is not intended for.

Comment: Thanks Remy. Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html) surprisingly worked.

Comment: In this case the server is using the `412 Precondition Failed` to tell you that pre-condition that they're placing on your request has failed. The precondition doesn't have to be based on any `If-...` header. **Source**: [the RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10.4.13) *(The precondition given in one or more of the request-header fields
   evaluated to false when it was tested on the server.)*

Comment: It's not just `If-...` headers; look at the `Accept` header. For me, I had specified `application/json` but the server could only return `text/html`.

Comment: It's not just `If-...` headers; look at the `Accept` header. For me, I had specified `application/json` but the server could only return `text/html`.